# Assigning a new File value to a an excel .xlsx file. JAVA

Tags: java, excel

I have this following portion of code that i don't get why it doesn't work.
I've checked the location of the file and it's fine, though, just to be sure i've changed it to a new location but the problem continues.

```
//resources is the paste where the jar file will get Inputs
File temp = new File("resources\\OEE_SETOR_LECTRAS.xlsx");
try {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(temp);
        XSSFWorkbook myWorkBook = new XSSFWorkbook (fis);
        XSSFSheet mySheet = myWorkBook.getSheetAt(6);
                             .
                             .
                             .
```

-->then when i call the function it throws this:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: *******.XLSX 
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: resources\\OEE_SETOR_LECTRAS.xlsx is not the path, give the complete path or you wanted to read the file from classpath?

Comment: The .xlsx file it's not in any package but in a place in C disk. like this: C:\\...\\****.xlsx file, the thing is, even if a give it the full path it still doesnt work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @ankush has already pointed out, it's not good way to load file from resources.

Try using

```
System.out.println(new File("resources\\OEE_SETOR_LECTRAS.xlsx").getAbsolutePath());
```

to check full path from where your program is trying to load the file.

If the defined xlsx file is in your your class path, try loading it via classloader.

```
Test.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("resources\\OEE_SETOR_LECTRAS.xlsx");
```

Comment: i've tried it out with a test class and the path is right, like i've said to @ankush , i've even wrote the full file path and it still doesnt work. Maybe it's because it's a xmlx file idk. Because when i try to Write a xls file it works with no problems.